# Firebase Realtime Database with Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am New to firebase, at starting work with firebase realtime database on web. i have written following code from showing one video. But code not works

```
<pre id="object"></pre>


<script>

    (function (){
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "<API KEY>",
            authDomain: "test-2c44d.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://test-2c44d.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "test-2c44d",
            storageBucket: "test-2c44d.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "329022996031"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const preObject = document.getElementById('object');

        const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');

        dbRefObject.on('value',snap => console.log(snap.val()));
    }());
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show any errors or the way you want it to work? It will help us create better answers.

Comment: No Error showing

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: No error but no output also.... I need output fetch data from db

Comment: I would suggest using `dbRefObject.then(function(snap) {console.log(snap.val());});`